# How can one determine CP's version?

Tags: core-plot

Simple question: Is there a simple way to check the current Core-Plot version running in an App?

Answer (score 1):

Once it's compiled into the app, no.

Comment: What's a quick/official way to determine the CP version in code, prior to build?

Comment: There aren't any compile-time constants or other version info available to the compiler or at run-time. What do you need the version number for?

Comment: To determine if we have the latest version; and any new vs deprecated APIs.

Comment: If you want to know if a particular method is available, you can use the `-respondsToSelector:` method. There aren't any deprecated APIs in recent versions (1.0+).